# Printing out name for each row of /etc/passwd file output

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have an assignment to print out information about a user from the `/etc/passwd` file. What I want is for the output to be column format instead of row format.

what I've managed to do is to get everything printed on new rows with help of the `tr` command, so the output right now is like the following.

```
user

x

1002

1002

/home/user

/bin/sh
```

but what i want is for the output to be like this.

```
username user

password x

user id 1002

group id 1002

comment

directory /home/user

shell /bin/sh
```

my code right now looks like this

```
    grep user /etc/passwd | tr ':' '\n'
```

Comment: Read up on awk.

Answer (score 1):

Just parse the file with `:` as the value of IFS.

```
wanted=user
grep ":$wanted:" /etc/passwd | # this grep alone not a great idea
  while IFS=: read usr pswd uid gid cmnt dir shell;
  do [[ "$usr" == "$wanted" ]] || continue # skip false hits 
     printf 'username %s\npassword %s\nuser id %s\ngroup id %s\n%s\ndirectory %s\nshell %s\n' "$usr" "$pswd" "$uid" "$gid" "$cmnt" "$dir" "$shell";
  done
```

The grep alone will give you false hits though. My first test gave me `username tss` when the comment was `Account used by the trousers package to sandbox the tcsd daemon` and `username saslauth` when comment was `Saslauthd user`.

Adding colons around it prevented false hits in my passwd file, but to be sure(r), explicitly check the user on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following shell script. I just wrote it for two fields such as `username` and `password`. I hope you can manage for other fields.

#### Script

```
while read line
do
  echo $line | awk -F':' '{print "Username: "$1"\nPassword: "$2"\n_______"}'
done</etc/passwd
```

#### OUTPUT

```
[root@967dd7743677 test]# while read line; do echo $line | awk -F':' '{ print "Username: " $1 "\nPassword: " $2 "\n______" }'; done</etc/passwd
    Username: root
    Password: x
    ______
    Username: bin
    Password: x
    ______
    Username: daemon
    Password: x
    ______
```

Comment: If you're parsing with `awk`, why are you wrapping it in a `while read` loop?